# What is the best way to access a class properties in php - magic methods or hardcoding setter & getters

Tags: php, oop, social-networking

What is the best way to access the property of a PHP Class? I can either use the Built-in php accessor magic methods or should I hard code the `get*()` and `set*()` methods. What would be most efficient and best for refactoring the code later on when I am working on a large code base. I am asking this for a very large code base. Think of it as a development of a social network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say what is better or worse if I don't know the purpose of it.

In my opinion it is better to use dedicated getter/setter and not coding `__get()` or `__set()` magic methods.

For the two reasons:

1. My IDE it will not auto-complete pseudo-properties that are coded in magic methods. I don't know what type the property should be and even if there is one with this name.
2. When I need to change behaviour of getter/setter it's easy to locate where it is. I change only the method code, not the large `__get()` or `__set()`.

Sometimes I use something like

```
public function __get($name){ // no error handling, but should be some
  return $this->{'get'.$name}();
}
```

and the getter as well

```
public function getX(){ ...}
public function getY(){ ...}
```

and so on.

This allows me to shorten typing, but leaving all to getter.

Calling a pseudo-property has also some disadvantage for me as any warning/error/exception/... would be sent in the `__get()` method, not the getter -- I would not know what `$name` was given and so on.

**EDIT**

Using dedicated methods for getting and setting properties is also more clear in inheritance. Documenting software can mark that the getter was overridden, so I know which class change the code, and which uses the code from it's ancestors. In `__get()` it will be marked overridden if I change code for `$name` eg. "coordinates", but I don't change "seaLevel" (I mean it's not always clear what has been overridden).